# Ruby - how to add a conditional key to a hash?

Tags: ruby, key-value

I have this method creating a hash:

```
def build_values(data)
  {
    key1: data.k1,
    key2: data.k2,
    key3: (@var == true ? data.k3 : nil),
    key4: data.k4,
    ...
  }
end
```

If `@var == true`, then `key3` has the value `data.k2`. That's good.

If it is not `true`, then `key3` has not value (actually, it has `nil`). But ideally, I would not want to print the `key3` at all.

How do I do that? Something like this doesn't work:

```
def build_values(data)
  {
    key1: data.k1,
    key2: data.k2,
    if @var == true
      key3: data.k3
    end,
    key4: data.k4,
    ...
  }
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not the prettiest solution, but `**` could be used:

```
{
  key1: data.k1,
  key2: data.k2,
  **(@var == true ? { key3: data.k3 } : {}),
  key4: data.k4,
}
```

Note that `== true` can be omitted if you just care whether `@var` is *truthy*.

Answer (score 1):

If you care for the order of keys, you can do:

```
def build_values(data)
  data = {
    key1: data.k1,
    key2: data.k2
  }
  data[:key3] = data.k3 if @var == true
  data.merge(
    key4: data.k4,
    ...
  }
end
```

Alternatively, you can use predefined key order (this could be hand when there are more optional keys):

```
KEY_ORDER = %i[key1 key2 key3 key4 ...]

def build_values(data)
  data = {
    key1: data.k1,
    key2: data.k2,
    key4: data.k4
  }
  data[:key3] = data.k3 if @var == true
  data.sort_by { |k, _| KEY_ORDER.index(k) }.to_h 
end
```

However, if you got here it might be worth considering a custom class - either Struct or even Hash subclass to deal with this data.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can consider something like [rejecting](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-reject) the key if not `@var`:

```
def build_values(data)
  {
    key1: data.k1,
    key2: data.k2,
    key3: data.k3,
    key4: data.k4
    }.reject{ |k, _| k == :key3 && !@var }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```rb
def build_values(data)
  hash = {
    key1: data.k1,
    key2: data.k2,
    key4: data.k4,
    ...
  }
  hash[:key3] = data.k3 if @var == true  
end
```